# Lightswitch HTML computed table column

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, calculated-columns

I've been researching this for a long while and still can't find anything that works. I have a lightswitch html client screen containing a table similar to the example scenario below:

CustomerId | CustomerName | DeliveryAddress

The screen data includes Customer_Orders (Id, CustId, Value) and I would like to add the average order value for each customer to my table as below:

CustomerId | CustomerName | DeliveryAddress | AverageValue

I have created a screen property called AverageValue and have entered everything I can find online into the AverageValue_PostRender function and the BrowseCustomers.TableRow_PostRender function.

So far, I have managed to pull out the customer data from the row and append it to the far right side of the table by using the following in the tablerow postrender function:

```
var name = $("<p>" + contentItem.value.Name + "</p>");
name.appendTo($(element));
```

and have managed to insert a test string into every row of the averagevalue column by using the following in the averagevalue postrender function:

```
contentItem.screen.AverageValue = "test";
```

but I have not been able to combine the two things and get customer data into the averagevalue column. 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is the data you want to calculate unsaved data or is it stored in a database? If so, you could create a computed field in the table and just display that.

Comment: The raw data (order value) is stored in the database, but the value I want to display (average value) is a calculated field. 
This entire question is here because I am unable to display a computed field on my screen. This is possible in lightswitch silverlight but not in lightswitch HTML.